# How to pass a function with implicit as parameter

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I want to pass a function `fun1` as a parameter to `fun2`.
However `fun1` needs an implicit parameter. Is is possible to define that implicit value inside `fun2`?

The code is like this:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

  def fun1(json:JValue)(implicit formats: Formats) = {

        //do something
  }


  def fun2(f: (JValue) => RatEvent,line:String ) = {

        implicit val formats = DefaultFormats  //has been defined in import
        val json = parse(line)  //covert string to jvalue
        val result = f(json)
  }
```

Here I pass `fun1` to `fun2`, compiler complains that it cannot find implicit value for fun1.

```
  fun2(fun1,"asdfasdf")    //error here,   fun1 is lack of an implicit value
```

I want to solve the problem by changing the shape of `fun2` i.e.

```
def fun2(f: (JValue)(implicit Formats) => RatEvent,line:String ) //doesn't compile
```

But I don't know how to write it correctly.

**Supplement:**

Declare an implicit Format may seems a good solution. But I have to define it in fun2. I have made problem simple. The real funs looks like:

```
  def fun2(f: (JValue) => RatEvent,lines:RDD[String] )(implicit sc:SparkContext) = {

        for (
          line <- lines
        ){
        implicit val formats = DefaultFormats  //has been defined in import
        val json = parse(line)  //covert string to jvalue
        val result = f(json)
        ......
        }
  }
```

`formats` has to be defined inside of `lines`'s `map` function (I used `for` instead).

Answer (score 2):

A Scala function value's `apply` method only has one parameter list and does not take any implicit parameters. You can't do anything about that.

You could change the shape of `fun2` to take the extra parameter as a normal parameter:

```
class J; class F; class R

def fun1(j: J)(implicit f: F): R =
  new R
def fun2(fn: (J, F) => R) {
  fn(new J, new F)
}

fun2(fun1(_)(_))
```

But yuck; the call site isn't as nice as the `fun2(fun1)` you wanted.

If you have an implicit F in scope at the call site, then you can change the shape of `fun2` as follows:

```
class J; class F; class R

def fun1(j: J)(implicit f: F): R =
  new R

def fun2(fn: J => R)(implicit f: F) {
  fn(new J)
}

implicit val f = new F
fun2(fun1)
```

Yay, clean call site!

Does this meet your requirements? In your question, you only have a `Formats` in implicit scope inside the body of `fun2`, but I can't tell if that's a necessary condition of your question, or just something accidental about the way you condensed your code to fit in a question.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I have to define `Formats` in `fun2`. I have updated question.

Comment: In that case, I don't see how to improve on the `fun2(fun1(_)(_))` solution.